# Base64 decode a string with ISO-8859-1 charset and save it into NSData

Tags: c#, ios, character-encoding, xamarin, base64

This is what I've now:

```
documentData = new NSData (document.String, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);
```

This does work, but it seems that NSData is using UTF-8 as output charset. But I need the data in ISO-8859-1 output charset to get the correct decoding. The default one (UTF-8) fails.

Is there an option for `NSData` or do I have to convert it with C#?

**Edit:**

Can I assume that ASCII is ISO-8859-1?

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (base64EncodedData))
            return null;

    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

I believe not.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Your `document.String` isn't in any encoding, it's a string. Encodings are applied to strings to convert them to binary.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. *document.String* is only a string. You can select the output charset like [here](https://www.base64decode.org/). If I take my base 64 encoded string and select UTF-8 nothing is displayed. For Latin-1 I get a result. The above constructor can do the decoding, but I can't select an output charset.

Comment: Ah, that's makes more sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `NSData`, but the [docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSData/) don't seem to indicate you can do this.

You can convert in C#, though:

```
var isoBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(document.String);
var utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"),
     Encoding.UTF8, isoBytes);
```

It looks like you could then initialise `NSData` from a factory method:

```
var nsData = NSData.FromArray(utf8Bytes);
```

Or convert it to base64 and use the constructor:

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(utf8Bytes);
var nsData = new NSData(base64, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None)
```

Comment: You have to use `FromArray` instead of `FromBytes`. One more question though: I have some problems with the umlauts. Instead of *ü* I get a wrong character *A 1/4*. Do you have a clue why?

Comment: Good spot.  Changed. The likely explanation is your encoding wasn't ISO-8859-1 so it's been corrupted on conversion to UTF8.  Have you got any sample inputs and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I'll have to look deeper into this but the rtf-file contains `ansi\ansicpg1252` in the header. The problematic text in the rtf-file is correctly shown, when I copy the debug output into an editor after conversion. Because it should be now in UTF-8 I display the content in a `UIWebview` with the text encoding UTF-8. Hmm ...

Comment: That sounds more like `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")` to me.

Comment: You can have a look about the inputs and outputs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472492/encoding-of-rtf-file).