# Encoding of rtf file

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, base64, rtf

I get a base64 encoded string which represents a rtf-file.

If I look the original text representation (before base64 encode) I see the character sequence `F¸r`. This should stand for `Für`, when displayed in a viewer. The header of the rtf-file contains `ansicpg1252` so this should be the encoding except otherwise changed (escape sequences, font definitions, ..).

My problem now is that I can't correctly decode the base 64 string to its original representation. I never get `F¸r` anymore. Instead I have `Für` or even `F\'fcr`. Through this the representation of the umlaut is wrong when displaying the decoded rtf in a viewer.

So what is the original encoding of the rtf-file? Or what is going wrong here?

You can have a look into a sample file [here](http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/BRAo7ppJ/file.html). [This](http://www4.zippyshare.com/v/EpXXPS0u/file.html) is the base 64 encoded string I get.

**Edit:**

I don't have the code for the encoding, but I think I can reconstruct that. This is my code for this:

```
string path = "/some/path/ltxt1 Kopie.rtf";
byte[] document = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(document);
var isoBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

File.WriteAllText ("/some/path/sketch.rtf", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(isoBytes));
```

I tried to change the encoding, but with `windows-1252` I get an error (sketch: encoding name not supported, real project: array not null).

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to encode and decode the contents?

Comment: I'm getting the content from a webservice and I can't get the code for the encoding. What I was told is that `iso-8859-1` should be used for the encoding. At least I have access to the original file. I update my question with what I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is not the encoding of the file.  If you run your code and compare the results, the text is the same in each.

Your issue is that the source file is ANSI encoded and your second file is UTF-8 encoded.  *However*, the RTF directive in the text tells whatever is interpreting the RTF that is it ANSI encoded (the `ansicpg1252` part).  So it then makes a total mess of decoding it due to the mismatch.

The simplest way around this is to make sure you write it back to disc using the matching encoding:

```
var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
File.WriteAllText("/some/path/sketch.rtf", iso.GetString(isoBytes), iso);
```

Or, more simply:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("/some/path/sketch.rtf", isoBytes);
```

Comment: It seems that you are right. For the file output it is working. Originally, I wanted to import it into [`NSData`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455532/base64-decode-a-string-with-iso-8859-1-charset-and-save-it-into-nsdata). If I do this with `NSData.FromArray(isoBytes)` I get completely wrong results. So I have to convert it? But to what? If I choose another encoding I get the problems again. The source encoding is 'Windows-1252`? I think this is not supported in my environment (Xamarin.iOS on Mac).

Comment: What do you want to do with it in `NSData`?  What's the goal?  You could convert to UTF8 to put into there and then convert back when you need it.

Comment: I'm using `NSData` for storing the data temporarily and then I represent the data in a `UIWebView`. I think I need to know which encoding it was before and I have to remember it. What is the source encoding? `Windows-1252`, `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: Now I tried to convert *isoBytes* to `UTF-8` and then I converted it back to `iso-8859-1`. Once I use `NSData` the encoding problem occurs again. Perhaps `iso-8859-1` is the wrong encoding ...

Comment: How are you doing this conversion and how are you loading the data into `UIWebView`?  (I'm quite unfamiliar with Xamarin, so apologies for my ignorance!)

Comment: No, thats not ignorance! I'm really thankful for your help. For the conversion I used `Encoding.Convert` and I pass the content for the webview like so: `webView.LoadData (documentData, "text/rtf", "iso-8859-1", new NSUrl ("/"));`

Comment: Presumably there's a mismatch there as `documentData` is now in UTF8. There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs that says it has to be UTF8 - it's just a buffer.  Can you not just use `NSData.FromArray(isoBytes)` without converting?

Comment: `NSData.FromArray(isoBytes)` seems to work! I've another filter algorithm in there, where I convert `NSData` to `string`. Is this possible without getting into encoding problems?

Comment: It seems the string conversions will assume UTF8, so to get it back correctly I think you'd do something like `iso.GetString(documentData.ToArray())`.

Comment: And back? I tried `var isoBytes = iso.GetBytes (documentString); documentData = NSData.FromArray (isoBytes);`, but here again I get a strange byte interpretation.

Comment: What's `documentString`?  If it's base64, you'll probably want to decode that first.

Comment: `documentString = iso.GetString(documentData.ToArray())`. Should I make a new question for that?

Comment: OK, now I did everything again and it seems to work. I'll test it a little bit more on Monday and then I give you the ticks :-D