# Wrong character encoding of rtf file

Tags: python, character-encoding, rtf

When I copy and paste the sentence `How brave they’ll all think me at home!` into a blank TextEdit rtf document on the Mac, it looks fine. But if I create an an apparently identical rtf file programatically, and write the same sentence into it, on opening TextEdit it appears as `How brave theyâ€™ll all think me at home!`  In the following code, `output` is OK, but the file when viewed in TextEdit has problems with the right single quotation mark (here used as an apostrophe), unicode U-2019.

```py
header = r"""{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf400
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0
\f0\fs24 \cf0 """

sen = 'How brave they’ll all think me at home!'

with open('staging.rtf', 'w+’) as f:
    f.write(header)
    f.write(sen)
    f.write('}')

with open('staging.rtf') as f:
    output = f.read()
print(output)
```

I’ve discovered from https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html that this may be caused by “UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as Windows-1252”, and that makes sense as it seems that `ansicpg1252` in the header indicates US Windows.

But I still can’t work out how to fix it, even having read the similar issue here: [Encoding of rtf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31472492/1726290). I’ve tried replacing `ansi` with `mac` without effect. And adding `,encoding='utf8'` to the open function doesn’t seem to help either.

(The reason for using rtf by the way is to be able to export sentences with colour-coded words, allow them to be manually edited, then read back in for further processing).

Comment: Can you add the code you’re using to generate the file to your question?

Comment: The file’s created by the first open statement, with the w+ option. The code should run as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer myself.  I needed to use `, encoding='windows-1252'` both when writing to the rtf file and also when reading from it.