# how to write the character `é` in an rft file?

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf, wordpad

I need to write a string from `c#` into an `rtf` file, but having weird problems.
To write the text I simply use

```
 string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".rtf";
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, body);
```

body is a string variable, that is filled from a `varchar` column from a database.

The problem is with the character `é` which is wrong displayed by wordpad when opening the file like this

[image]

If I open the file in notepad, I see this

```
(één schade gevonden -> ander dossier)
```

So for some dark reason wordpad decided to show the character `é` all messed up like this.

I tried writing the file as `UTF8` or other `unicode` encodings, but then wordpad refused to see this file as `rtf` and just shows the plain text with all the tags

I also looked at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) page where it tells me to write a tag like  `\uXXX?` where XXX should be a number defining a `Unicode UTF-16 code unit number`.
But I cannot find what number to use, or any good example on how to do this.

Actually I am not even sure if its unicode related, the character `é` is not even a character that needs unicode in my mind, could be wrong off course.

Anyway, does anyone knows how to solve this problem ?
I just need a way to make `wordpad` not mess up the character `é` on display and on print.

Comment: Maybe [Encoding of rtf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31472492/205233) holds some clue.

Comment: It got encoded to plain text (not RTF) in utf8, without a BOM.  Wordpad didn't stand a chance.  Use RichTextBox.SaveFile() to write RTF.

Comment: @Filburt Thank you for the link, I found my answer there

Comment: @Filburt OK I just did, but not sure if its not actually a duplicate after all...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I did not encoded the `RTF` file properly.
Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31472492/205233) provided by Filburt I managed to encode the `RTF` file correct like this.

```
var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".rtf";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, body, iso);
```

Comment: No, that is still not a RTF file.  If you want to write a text file then use the .txt filename extension.  ISO-8859-1 is not correct either and merely happened to work by accident.  Use Encoding.Default instead to match the encoding that other programs will use when they can't see a BOM in a text file.  Such a file shouldn't travel very far away from your machine, the default encoding depends on the user's locale.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you provide a little example on how to do this ? Im a complete noob when it comes to RTF

Comment: Are you even sure you want to generate RTF?  It is only useful if the text needs to have style changes, like different fonts or colors.  RichTextBox.SaveFile() is not complicated to use, just assign its Text property first.

Comment: @HansPassant Well I dont need RTF exact, but its the only text format I could find where I could do `Page Breaks` that starts a new page in the printer. That is why I used it now

Comment: @HansPassant If I would fill up a RichtTextBox, then how can I insert `\page` (page breaks) in `C#` code ?

Comment: Well, you certainly forgot to ask the real question you need an answer to.