# Receive NSData in c#

Tags: c#, nsdata

We have to create an app where my iOS developer will send video to my ASP.Net web api in NSData format.Th web api in c# has to receive this data and save it on AWS server after decoding it to its mp4 format.
How can I decode the NSData? Can someone guide me on this.

So far I have tried simple video upload to AWS server and it works fine.

Comment: NSData is just Obj-C's name for a blob of binary, right? You could always convert it to base 64 and just send it in an HTTP POST.

Comment: plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31456010/2318852